# Bootstrap container-fluid not responsive after certain width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, responsive-design

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.5 grid system.

**HTML** (*not sure it'll help*)

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid containerResize">
        <header class="row">
            ...
        </header>

        <main class="row">
            ...
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS** (*for `.containerResize`*)

```
.containerResize {
    height: 100%;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

This error is temperamental.

Sometimes the container will resize perfectly down to whatever size but a lot of the time when I resize the width **below 970px**, the container will not longer resize and stay at 970px. This is interfering with my responsive design as components within the container rely on it's width. I'm running it in **Chrome**. I've had a suggestion that it might be a Chrome related issue?

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT**

It works in Firefox

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: Do you have a live example?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't as it is run locally